# Hide toolbar in activity by scrolling a recyclerview inside the Fragment?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

**My Activity XML is**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:title="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/navview_text_color"
        app:menu="@menu/home_drawer_items_menu"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**My Fragment XML is :**

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewPager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My `fragment` uses `tabs` and `nested fragments` inside the `ViewPager` and my `activity` uses `navigation drawer` so i can't move the `tabs` to `activity` as the tabs are only needed for this specific `fragment`. And other fragments just need a `toolbar`. At the same time all the fragments need to access the `navigation drawer`.

Now what i want to do is somehow associate `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`
with my activity's toolbar. So that whenever i scroll my `RecyclerView` inside the `fragment` the `toolbar` in the activity gets hidden.

It would be great if you guys can point me in the right direction or help me figure out how to do this ?

Comment: This lib might be able to help you : https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: @Ben-J thanks for the library it seems to be a good workaround but its still missing the animation that happens when we are using `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue, though there is still room for some minor improvements like the `FAB` is moving **up** and **down** whenever i scroll `RecyclerView` inside the `Fragment`

In order to make `toolbar` respond to `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` this is what i did

**I changed my Activity XML to:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:title="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/navview_text_color"
        app:menu="@menu/home_drawer_items_menu"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Also i changed my Fragment XML to:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:elevation="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" adding this to the container layout will make the container translate down hence any view graviting bottom inside the fragments will no longer be visible ;(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly what you can do is

1) Include the Toolbar and  `NavigationDrawer` in `MainActivity` so it will be accessible in all fragments too.

2) Include tabs in in only `ParentFragment` which contains `ViewPager` for other fragments

with this approach your Toolbar and `NavigationDrawer` will be visible in all fragments while tabs only in `ParentFragment`

Hope it helps

Comment: what you said, i have already done that. Please read the question again. I want to hide the toolbar when i scroll recyclerview in fragment.

Comment: why don't you use [onScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html)?

Comment: I am using that for now but that still doesnt give me the smooth animation that `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` gives me

Comment: have you tried built in animation `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`? I have used it for hiding and showing `AppbarLayout` and it works well

Comment: Yes tried that but it will gives a jerk in ui. Not as smooth as the normal behavior

Answer (score -2):

Also ran into this problem. But a solution was found. The solution with xml rework can not be, so you need to do it programmatically. All we need is **Inflater**. Yes, yes, that's so simple. On the fly change xml to work all scrolling.
Inflate/AddView/RemoveView - that's all you need!